# handle file using session but multiple session

Tags: php, session

i will handling scurity file with session, but i have problem.

i have filea.php with session.

```
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['login']){ 
include('fileb.php');   
    }
```

i have fileb.php with session.

```
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['login']){

    } else {
// redirect to login
}
```

i will include fileb.php in filea.php using include file

my filea.php

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['login']){
include('fileb.php');
}
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: `$_SESSION['login']` is assigned where exactly?

Comment: is assigned in from login, how to handle multiple `session_start();`

Comment: when a user not login can access can access fileb.php, are you have solution when user not login can't access fileb.php ?

Comment: sorry, your script need `session_start();` in fileb.php, when include in filea.php, output is error in filea.php

Comment: If the problem is only because of multiple session_start(), consider using the following to start session IF it is not already started, else you can bypass with: `if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE){session_start();}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just using **session_start()** on *fileA and fileB*, you could use:

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE){session_start();}
```

This will ensure that session will be started only if it is not already set, else will be skipped.

Similarly to see if **SESSION variables** are set or not, consider using:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    // Your codes here
}
```

Where, I assume that you have managed the session variables somewhere else and is working properly.